# Spring Boot: substitute @Configuration class with another

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a custom configuration class that I am loading using spring factories during bootstrap. The problem is that it is being overwritten by another similar configuration class coming from a spring ** starter package. I've tried excluding the second one, but it still loads. Also tried to set priorities, but that didn't work too.

Here's a snippet of my custom configuration class:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAwsParamStorePropertySourceLocatorConfig implements PropertySourceLocator
...
```

And the one I'm trying to exclude that is coming from spring boot aws starter:

```
public class AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator implements PropertySourceLocator {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration class has the ConditionalOnProperty annotation at the class level...

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AwsParamStoreProperties.class)
@ConditionalOnClass({ AWSSimpleSystemsManagement.class, AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator.class })
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = AwsParamStoreProperties.CONFIG_PREFIX, name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration {

    private final Environment environment;

    public AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator awsParamStorePropertySourceLocator(AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssmClient,
            AwsParamStoreProperties properties) {
        if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(properties.getName())) {
            properties.setName(this.environment.getProperty("spring.application.name"));
        }
        return new AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator(ssmClient, properties);
    }
```

So if you configured the property `aws.paramstore.enabled=false` it should stop that configuration from creating the AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator bean.

It's important to note, that would also stop the creation of the AWSSimpleSystemsManagement bean which is also created in the AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration class, so if you require that bean, you may need to also create it in your custom Configuration class.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssmClient(AwsParamStoreProperties properties) {
    return createSimpleSystemManagementClient(properties);
}

public static AWSSimpleSystemsManagement createSimpleSystemManagementClient(AwsParamStoreProperties properties) {
    AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder builder = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard()
            .withClientConfiguration(SpringCloudClientConfiguration.getClientConfiguration());
    if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(properties.getRegion())) {
        builder.withRegion(properties.getRegion());
    }
    if (properties.getEndpoint() != null) {
        AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                properties.getEndpoint().toString(), null);
        builder.withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration);
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: how to create this bean? Are there some examples somewhere?

Comment: Also when trying this out I get the following error: `Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in io.protel.smp.config.CustomAwsParamStorePropertySourceLocatorConfig required a bean of type 'com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagement' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
 - Bean method 'ssmClient' in 'AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (aws.paramstore.enabled) found different value in property 'enabled'`

Comment: updated the answer to show how it is created in `AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration.java`.  Code is at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/main/spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/paramstore/AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration.java

Comment: still I get the error, that the candidates were found, but could not be injected as above ^

Comment: Can you post your CustomAwsParamStorePropertySourceLocatorConfig  class?

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense to use the param store starter from spring cloud. It just has too many things preconfigured that I want to do in another way. I guess I have to use the vanilla AWS sdk.